# DDD - ConcurrencySafeEntity what is it being used for

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design

In the book Implementing domain driven design by Vaughn Vernon, he has employed a super type called ConcurrencySafeEntity, but couldn't find a specific explanation as to what is the exact purpose of this class, would appreciate any explanation in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConcurrencySafeEntity` class is a [Layer Supertype](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html) which avoids code duplication for entities that needs to implement [optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) in order to prevent concurrency problems.

Comment: Thanks, can you help elaborate on how it avoid the problems of concurrency using the version number member

Comment: Well, that's not your initial question and that is explained plenty in the book already. Just search on the internet for "The lost update problem", "race conditions" and "optimistic concurrency".

Comment: So after acquiring some clarifications, here is my understanding, to ensure transnational consistency of a aggregate, the aggregate is striped with the version number or a timestamp, this ensures the aggregate is not modified concurrently, but an incorrectly designed aggregate(like large cluster of objects in a single aggregate) might lead to undesired contention of resources leading to bad user experience.

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar Exactly! In the IDDD book Vaughn also gave optimistic concurrency versions to individual entities meaning that you might be able to modify an entity without bumping the root version, but I'm not sure it's a good practice because I don't think you could do this with a document database.

Comment: [Here's Vernon's source code from GitHub](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_common/src/main/java/com/saasovation/common/domain/model/ConcurrencySafeEntity.java).